# Dissolving polygon features with duplicate set of attributes

Tags: pyqgis, dissolve

I have one shapefile with thousands of polygon features. Many of them have the exact sets of attributes. So I want to make those features into one so that I can reduce the number of features from a few thousands to, say, ten to twenty.

I found the Polygon dissolve (by attributes) tool quite similar to what i want but I can only input 3 attributes in the GUI. But I want to input all attributes. Is it possible to do it in PyQGIS?

Comment: Dissolve doesn't seem like the correct operation. I'd recommend setting a goal of selecting the "best" version of each feature, then exporting this set to a new shapefile.